# Google polymer - what are bundled elements?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Looking at documentation of a paper-input element, I see a section "Bundled elements". What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing paper-input using the Bower command just above your arrow will download all the bundled elements and behaviours. You could still use them individually, though. Also, if you import paper-input.html, the bundled elements and behaviours will also be imported. Thus you only need to import paper-input.html and you can then use all elements and behaviours in the bundle.